# cant execute binary inside docker container but from host machine

Tags: docker, go

I have a docker container based on `composer:1.8`(based on `php:7-alpine`).

Inside the container I download a `tar.gz` via php, decompress it and extract it which works fine.
This contains a Go binary I want to execute.
When executing the binary inside the docker container I get this error message: `./bin/<binary>: No such file or directory`. On my host machine I can execute this binary downloaded inside the docker container perfectly fine.

If it is important I start the docker container with: `docker run -it --rm --volume=$PWD:/usr/src/myapp -u $(id -u):$(id -g) --name ec ec /bin/bash`

I also tried to run `readelf -a <binary>` after installing it, but that doesn't have any effect.

```
bash-4.4$ ls -l <binary> && echo userid: $(id -u) && echo groupid: $(id -g) && uname -om && ./<binary>
-rwxr-xr-x    1 1000     985        7582050 Mar 15 17:09 <binary>
userid: 1000
groupid: 985
x86_64 Linux
bash: ./<binary>: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Is your $PWD a constant? For ex, are you able to do `ls` inside the container and find the other files? Or maybe you could try to `touch dummyfile` on the host and then through your container do `ls` and verify if the setup is as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the binary is compiled using `glibc` and alpine using `musl`.
I've got around with it to pass my binary the `CGO_ENABLED=0` environment variable while building